# python-sphinx, NULL-BYTES in config files

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a problem regarding sphinx, for python documentation generation. I installed it from source, but every time I try to create a setup using:

```
sphinx-quickstart
```

The files that are generated, for example the make.bat and the index.rst look like this:

```
'@\x00E\x00C\x00H\x00O\x00 \x00O\x00F\x00F\x00\r\x00\n',
'\x00\r\x00\n',
'\x00R\x00E\x00M\x00 \x00C\x00o\x00m\x00m\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00 \x00f\x00i\x00l\x00e\x00   \x00f\x00o\x00r\x00 \x00S\x00p\x00h\x00i\x00n\x00x\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00c\x00u\x00m\x00e \x00n\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00\r\x00\n', ....
```

So NULL-Bytes I guess.

Of course when I'm trying to make the actual documentation I get several errors:

```
$ make html

Makefile:1: warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored, .....
```

or manually,

```
$sphinx-build -b html source target

Exception occurred:
 File "/xxxx/xxxxx/PyAdditionalPackages/lib/python/Sphinx-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/sphinx  /util/pycompat.py", line 96, in execfile_
code = compile(source, filepath_enc, 'exec')
TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes
```

I guess the problem is not directly sphinx related?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, if it matters.

P.S. On another machine, where I actually have sudo rights and installed using apt-get it works like a charm.

Comment: Any chance you have set your encoding to UTF-16?  What does `locale` on the command line say?  And `import sys` and then `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` in a Python shell?

Comment: No, both return UTF-8. The Problem also remains if I manually remove all '\x00' entries

Comment: First I will refer to your comment that on another machine everything works great - have you tried to run `sudo make html` on this machine? I also recommend running `make clean html` to remove any past build. Finally, the `.rst` file should not look like this (or maybe I didn't understand what you are pasting there?), it's a sort-of-markdown file. In case this could be of any use - I once made a tutorial for Sphinx that may help with your onboarding - dalyag.github.io/Sphinx185/index.html